# How to control size of list-style-type disc in CSS?

Tags: css

My HTML first:

```
<ul class="moreLinks" >
    <div>More from Travelandleisure.com</div>

        <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know that I can apply font-size on li very small so that disc look correct to me and then apply css to "a" inside li. But I do not know why this is not working on the site I am working. I cannot control the html directly.

I saw that when I make this:

```
.farParentDiv ul li {
    list-style: disc inside none;
}
```

TO this:

```
.farParentDiv ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

and now after applying font-size to "a", it works in Firebug. but from my css file. I tried a lot but tired. I can overwrite the above this in css file but cannot change it directly as I did in firebug.  Please write what can be the problem?

I used to put dots (.) just before link inside  and then apply css on that to control the disc size, but as I said, I cannot control the HTML.

Comment: You have some good details, but you don't actually show a non-working example. Put a complete (yet minimal) example on JSFiddle.net, or give a link to your actual site. There could be a variety of reasons related to selector specificity that might be overriding it in your actual case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have always had good luck with using background images instead of trusting all browsers to interpret the bullet in exactly the same way. This would also give you tight control over the size of the bullet.

```
.moreLinks li {
    background: url("bullet.gif") no-repeat left 5px;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Also, you may want to move your `DIV` outside of the `UL`. It's invalid markup as you have it now. You can use a list header `LH` if you must have it inside the list.

Comment: See also `list-style-image`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image

Comment: I know that solution, but I am not a media guy so was trying to fix it using CSS. But now I got image from colleague and I am happy. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this solution I got:
.li:before {
   content: " \2219 ";
}
but this too hackish solution and does not work correctly. but ok someone can play with it!

Comment: Notice that the background-image solution could cause **problems on mobile devices / screens with different default font size**. The background image wouldn't scale with the font size. Therefore I prefer the `li:before content` solution.

Answer (score 142):

Since I don't know how to control only the list marker size with CSS and no one's offered this yet, you can use `:before` content to generate the bullets:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li:before {
    content:"·";
    font-size:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wDL5/

The markers are limited to appearing "inside" with this particular CSS, although you could change it. It's definitely not the best option (browser must support generated content, so no IE6 or 7), but it might be the easiest - plus you can choose any character you want for the marker.

If you go the image route, see [`list-style-image`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image).

Comment: Good one! I tried that and got success but I was using vertical-align in li and not in li:before. Due to this my dots was coming on top. 
I saw another problem with this approach. It is SEO wise. If I sets font-size=50px for dots in your example then it looks correct for me. But font-size=50px can be bigger than h1 on page.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't use this unless it was really important to control the marker size, and you wanted to avoid a background image (I always try to avoid using images). However, I don't see what it has to do with SEO... If you're concerned with font size I would use percentages rather than px or ems and you should be able to get it right.

Comment: You rightly guessed. Google possibly checks font-size as well so that people cannot mislead it.

Comment: You can solve the "inside" problem by making the bullet absolute. Add the following CSS and it looks better (in my opinion)
    li {
        position:relative;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    li:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 3px;
    }
See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wDL5/459/)

Comment: `li:before { content:"•"; font-size:15px; vertical-align:top; padding-right:7px; }`

Comment: +1 for bringing up the idea of using :before selector.

Comment: This solution displayed as square instead of circle for me, but comment of @KaiNoack solved the issue! Thanks everybody!

Comment: Better to use the unicode for a disc rather than the non-keyboard character: `content:'\2022';`

Comment: just for **iOS developers**: This certainly works in the browser, but if you want to render HTML into a textview/uilabel: the `before` tag seems to net get converted correctly into `NSAttributedString` hence you might want to avoid using `before`. I realized that I had to stick with using `list-style`. That was supported.

Comment: I like this solution, while the font-size and alignment were a little odd for me, I cut those out/adjusted and it was perfect.  Also thanks to @brien-malone for his `content: '\2022'` comment/suggestion.   Thanks all!

Answer (score 33):

In modern browsers you can use the [::marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) CSS pseudo-element like this:

```
.farParentDiv ul li::marker {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

For browser support, please refer to: [Can I Use ::marker pseudo-element](https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo)

Comment: how can you adjust to where the mark lay (vertically) so it would center with the paragraph after changing the font size?

Answer (score 19):

If you choose to use inline SVG to render your bullets, you can use *width* and *height* properties to control their size:

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-1 -1 2 2'><circle r='1' /></svg>");
}

.x {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-1 -1 2 2'><circle r='0.5' /></svg>");
}

.x_alternative {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-2.2 -2.4 4 4'><circle r='1' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

<ul class="x">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

<ul class="x_alternative">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61104356/4684797) for an easy explanation of the viewBox.

Comment: But it does not seem to be possible to control the position. If you change the size to 5, then the dots are not centered anymore.

Comment: @Black true. I couldn't find any way to lift the text above the baseline of the SVG image either (evil [hacks](https://gist.github.com/kolja/a669d94cd9f8dfd45dc06afd30f77e01) aside). Text sized bullets will have to do for this answer, I guess.

Comment: I figured it out, I added two more examples. In the first one I changed the radius from 1 to .5; And in the second one I solved it by changing the viewbox

Comment: I hope it is ok for you that I added more examples and a link to my answer where I explain the viewBox.

Answer (score 9):

try to use diffrent font-size for li and a

```css
.farParentDiv ul li {
   list-style-type: disc;
   font-size:20px;
}

.farParentDiv ul li a {
   font-size:10px;
}
```

this saved me from using images

Comment: I use your code without list-style-type: disc; and it works well too thanks

Comment: Can't do this with `<li>text</li>`, unfortunately.

Comment: Best answer! Just put a span inside and give the style `<li class="small-fontsize"><span class="bigger-fontsize">Text</span></li>`

Answer (score 9):

I am buliding up on [Kolja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51723056/4684797), to explain how viewBox works

**The viewBox is a coordinate system.**

**Syntax:** `viewBox="posX posY width height"`

`viewBox="0 0 4 4"` will create this coordinate system:

The yellow area is the visible area.

So if you like to center something in it, then you need to use `viewBox='-2 -2 4 4'`

[image: Coordinate System]

I know it looks ridiculous and I also don't understand why they designed it this way...

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-2 -2 4 4'><circle r='1' /></svg>");
}

.x {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-2 -2 4 4'><circle r='.5' /></svg>");
}

.y {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-3 -2 4 4'><circle r='.5' /></svg>");
}

.z {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-3.5 -2 4 4'><circle r='.5' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
Centered Circle (viewBox Method) [viewBox='-2 -2 4 4', circle r='1']:

<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

Decrease Circle Radius [viewBox='-2 -2 4 4', circle r='.5']:

<ul class="x">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

Move Circle Closer to Text [viewBox='-3 -2 4 4', circle r='.5']:

<ul class="y">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

...even closer (use float values) [viewBox='-3.5 -2 4 4', circle r='.5']:

<ul class="z">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

But there is a much easier method, you can just use the circles `cx` and `cy` attributes.

```css
.centered {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='20' /></svg>");
}

.x {
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='10' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
Centered Circle (cx/xy) Radius 20 [viewBox='0 0 100 100', circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='20']:

<ul class="centered_a">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>

Centered Circle (cx/xy) Radius 10 [viewBox='0 0 100 100', circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='10']:

<ul class="x">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from using custom images for bullets, you can also style the ul or li elements one way and then style the contents differently, [as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/GJ84Y/2/).

The benefit is the lack of images for one thing, and also the added control. The disadvantage is that it tends to involve non-semantic markup, except in this case where the anchors are required already.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `position: absolute`, `text-indent` can be used to solve the "inside" problem:

```
li {
    list-style: inherit;
    margin: 0 0 4px 9px;
    text-indent: -9px;
}
li:before {
    content: "· ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/zEMLG/

Comment: Useful to be known, but not for this topic. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

When I add `list-style-type: disc;` to `ul` then in **Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (arm64)**, I see this. maybe some browsers haven't been supported this pseudo-element.

[image: marker-pseudo-element]

I modified the `li` disc size by this CSS:

```css
.htmlRenderer ul li::marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

But please consider the support range of this new feature:

[image: mdn-marker-pseudo-element]
[image: caniuse-marker-pseudo-element]

Answer (score 3):

I think by using the content"."; The dot becomes too squared if made too big, thus I believe that this is a better solution, here you can decide the size of the "disc" without affecting the font size.

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
   display: list-item;
   margin-left: 50px;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
   border: 5px #000 solid !important;
   border-radius: 50px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: -20px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h2>Look at these examples!</h2>
<li>This is an example</li>
<li>This is another example</li>
```

You edit the size of the disk by editing the size of the border px. and you can adjust the distance to the text by how much - margin left you give it. As well as adjust the y position by editing the margin top.

Comment: This is a nice hack, but for some reason the bullets didn't look quite round in my case, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for me is to use Unicode Characters and then style them with span tags. I'm going to use inline css for the sake of the example, but you can do it whatever way you prefer.

eg. When I want to use a square bullet and control its color and size:

```
<li style="list-style:none;"><a href=""><span style="font-size:x-small;vertical-align:middle;">&#9608;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</a></li>
```

You can find lots of unicode bullets here:

http://unicode-table.com/

I do this because linking images for bullets seems a little unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 2D transform. It is illustrated in the snippet below with a list being scaled by 25%.

> **Nota**: *Bootstrap is used here for the sole purpose of layouting the demo (before/after effect).*

---

```css
ul#before {
}

ul#after {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

div.container, div.row {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  border: 6px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      Before
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      After (scale 25%)
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <ul id="before">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
        <li>In vel ante vel est accumsan...</li>
        <li>In elementum libero vel...</li>
        <li>Nam ut ante a sem mattis...</li>
        <li>Curabitur fermentum nisl...</li>
        <li>Praesent vel risus ultrices...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      <ul id="after">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
        <li>In vel ante vel est accumsan...</li>
        <li>In elementum libero vel...</li>
        <li>Nam ut ante a sem mattis...</li>
        <li>Curabitur fermentum nisl...</li>
        <li>Praesent vel risus ultrices...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Reference:

- [CSS3 2D transform: compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: Does this do what the OP asked for? Seems like it scales the text along with the bullets. Also, it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for your comment. I remove the `zoom` property in favor of the standard one `transform:scale()`. The sample code in the post has been clarified too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned the list-style-image property

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('images/ico-list-bullet.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am attaching my solution that works perfectly in responsive too and you can control the size of the bullet very easily.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: -15px; /* Same negative margin as li padding  */
}
```

```html
<div><h3>More from Travelandleisure.com</h3></div>

<ul class="moreLinks" >
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="">xyz1</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>My example with lengthy text to show more clear result</h3>

<ul>
  <li>Quisque nibh mauris</li>
  <li>hired in he unable his thing rung and, in that films recommendation of the writing poster meticulous rewritten value comment finally, a the that low necessary fellow take fail then hope up, nor may needs better orthographic put took derisively to trumpet
    covered her be the offer, hotel would differences material. With mild, fact, the slide and, furnished as than with to the he she sides from where represent principles, in this ran derivative found was step after how to case privilege text a he tone
    inn so two through well, on is at knows, help people.</li>
  <li>Dictum lacinia dui</li>
  <li>Vestibulum dignissim imperdiet</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks