# is there any way to decrease List bullet size in CSS

Tags: css

[Here](http://clients.onebricktech.com/gaofeng/career.html) Is the link of the page on which I am working.

In the CONSULTANT section there is a list. I want to make the bullets size smaller.

I have done CSS:

```
.career ul li span {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.career ul li{
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Please help me to make bullets size smaller.

Thanks

Comment: Changing li font-size should work ... Checked, and it seems to work on your page. You have a 10px rule set ..

Comment: bullets are already small in your site using `..career ul li {
    list-style: square;
    font-size: 10px;
}`  But Associates bullets are larger of `font-size:18px` please try to remove cache or use `ctrl + F5`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control size of list-style-type disc in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990429/how-to-control-size-of-list-style-type-disc-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your HTML page. so that you're not able to decrease Bullet size

Comment: You Sir are a genius. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 3):

@trainoasis is right, decreasing the font-fize for li works. Tried with ChromeDeveloper tools, but this CSS should do the trick.

```
.career ul li {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: I have selected em, to make it more dramatic:) In your project you should use px instead:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:before` to create your own bullet and have it's own `font-size`

```
.career ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.career ul li:before {
  content: '■'; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qqzsLar/4/)

Comment: Good solution since it gives you full control over the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the size of bullet list, we can use before pseudo element.

For the list we have to give

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

And then using pseudo element, we can create bullet as per our needed size and content

```
ul li:before {
    content: ".";
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can style the positions by giving top,bottom,left, right values.

If you have any queries please check,
http://frontendsupport.blogspot.com/2018/05/reduce-bullet-size-in-list.html

Code was taken from the above site.