# How do I place the red dot before the selected item using CSS?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown with the following options:
[image]

The currently selected item is highlighted in red. And there is a Red Dot placed before the current selection.

Is there any way to get the red circle using pure CSS? like with the ::before selector?

The code for the dropdown list item is shown below:

```
<li key={option.value}>
    <a
        className={
            this.state.value === option.value
                ? 'category-link active'
                : 'category-link'
        }
        href="#!"
        onClick={() =>
            this.handleCategoryChange(option.value)
        }
    >
        {option.label}
    </a>
</li>
```

I toggle the anchor tag with active class to indicate red color.

```
.category-link {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;

    &.active {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #db2a30;
    }
}
```

So, all that remains is to show the red circle !!! It is not straight-forward as it seems because:

1. The red circle is bigger than the disc of a list-item.
2. The red circle is centered, and not anchored to the bottom.

Comment: *Is there any way to get the red circle using pure CSS? like with the ::before selector?* - Yes.

Comment: why not use an unordered list and style the bullets

Comment: @Pete Not possible to style individual list items! It applies at <ul> or list level.

Comment: Err, yes it is, you're just too lazy to try something yourself https://jsfiddle.net/Ltnabmhj/

Comment: Thanks @Pete, It works, but not able to adjust the size of the disc.

Comment: yes you can, just learn how to css for lists and no I'm not going to spoon feed you

Comment: Thanks @Pete. Did some more research and found this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990429/how-to-control-size-of-list-style-type-disc-in-css. Lot of info about list-items. Learned quite a bit today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can here is a jsbin example https://jsbin.com/caqegez/edit?html,css,output

html

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li class="selected">item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three</li>
    <li>item four</li>
    <li>item five</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.myList {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.myList > li {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
  color: grey;
}

.myList > li.selected {
  color: red;
}

.myList > li:before {
  display: inline-block;
   content: '';
   height: 0.75rem;
   width: 0.75rem;
   margin-right: 1em;
}

.myList > li.selected:before {
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi look at my example : https://codepen.io/TokaLazy/pen/JpWEEY

```
.category-link.active {
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.category-link.active::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: .65em;
    width: .65em;
    background: currentColor;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -.65em; // size of bullet 
    transform: translateY(-50%); // vertical alignment
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Very intuitive and easy to understand.